# Is the location displayed on screen - google maps on android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a location with its latitude and longitude. I want to check if these locations are displayed on screen when user changes the camera position or zoom. If screen contains this location, I want to get true, else false. Is it possible to determine it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to do this is to check if your Marker is inside the bounds of the visible region of the map.

```
Marker myPosition;//get your marker
LatLngBounds bounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
if(bounds.contains(myPosition.getPosition())){
  //point is visible
}else{
  //not visible
}
```